# My PLC does not provide an IP address inside my local network

Tags: networking, ip, raspberry-pi

I am trying to setup my Raspberry Pi to act like a Steam Link but I need my computer to be visible to my Pi. The thing is that I have my computer connected to the internet using a PLC (this one: https://www.tp-link.com/es/products/details/cat-5034_TL-PA4010P-KIT.html) and it is giving me an IP address that is out of my local network (different to 192.168.0.xx).

Thanks to https://whatismyipaddress.com/ I have been able to determine that the IP that has been assigned to the computer is the same that appears on that webpage when the normal output that you'll get from the site will be the IP of your router. So it's like the PLC is giving me direct access to the internet instead of going through the router itself.

I have tried to change the IP of the adapter manually, and it gave access from my laptop to my computer but the computer couldn't reach the Pi at all.

PD: my computer is running Windows 10, and the Raspberry pi is running RetroPi and the IP I am getting is 83.97.XX.XX

Comment: So what address is it assigning exactly?

Comment: You should edit your question to indicate the subnet, we don’t need to know, your public up address

Comment: So you mean that I have to add the subnet mask and the gateway?

Comment: *83.97.x.x* is enough information for this exercise.

Comment: When your raspberry pi is connected to the PLC and the other side of the PLC is connected to your router - your router should provide DHCP to your Raspberry Pi. Check your router and see if can check on the DHCP log to see what host has requested DHCP, and usually you get the list of IPs as well. Using Whatismyipaddress will only provide you the "external/public facing" IP. Not the IP of the machine you are on. Within your own LAN (behind the router) - you have your own IP range/subnet.

Comment: The thing is that the external IP of my computer matches its own IP. If I enter with my laptop in that webpage, I see the IP of my router, but from the computer connected to the PLC's the IP that I see is the IP of the computer itself (the local IP)